# Java has Object class. What class is there in Javascript for similar purpose?

Tags: javascript, oop

Here is a scenario. I have a class named business and business has a domain like food, entertainment etc. Business class has properties like id,name and reference to domain. I will create different domain classes like Food, Entertainment and Garments. Each domain class will have their own properties(few may be common).
If it was Java, I could simply use Object class or some interface which would have allowed me to provide reference of any of these types at runtime.
But I don't know how I can achieve this in Javascript. Any help will be appreciated in this regard.

Comment: Javascript variable can hold any data type be it array, object, boolean and even function too.

Comment: In JS variables don't have types (values do), so you don't need an `interface` in the sense that Java has them. You can just provide any of those objects at runtime and use their properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean what type would you use for the variable referencing instances of these classes, the answer is: None, JavaScript is a loosely-typed language. You just use whatever the variable/function argument/property contains:

```js
function Foo() {
    this.name = "foo";
}

function Bar() {
    this.name = "bar";
}

function Bingo() {
    this.name = "bingo";
}

function use(x) { // <== No type on `x`
    console.log(x.name);
}

use(new Foo());
use(new Bar());
use(new Bingo());
```

Or with ES2015+

```js
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.name = "foo";
    }
}

class Bar {
    constructor() {
        this.name = "bar";
    }
}

class Bingo {
    constructor() {
        this.name = "bingo";
    }
}

function use(x) { // <== No type on `x`
    console.log(x.name);
}

use(new Foo());
use(new Bar());
use(new Bingo());
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the separate type of variable in `Javascript`. `Javascript` is very different compared to `Java` ( and awesome )

```
var a = 10;
var b = "PieChuckerr Here!"
var isMale = true;
var countriesLivedIn = ['US', 'UK', 10, 12]; // country_code as well as name
var doCall = function(){}
var obj = {
  eyecolor: "blue",
  age: 30
}
```

Check this example Varible can hold any data type.

Answer (score 0):

If you come from Java, here is an exemple of migration from Java to JavaScript

the Java code :

```
public class Cellule { 

    // properties
    private String name = ""; 
    private Owner owner = null; 

    // constructor 
    public Cellule(String name){ 
        this.setName(name); 
    } 

    // méthods --> setter and getter 
    public String getName() { 
        return name; 
    } 

    public void setName(String name) { 
        this.name = name; 
    } 

    public Owner getOwner() { 
        return owner; 
    } 

    public void setOwner(Owner owner) { 
        this.owner = owner; 
    } 
} 

public class Owner  
{ 
    // properties
    private ArrayList<Cellule> cellules; 

    // constructor 
    public Owner(){ 
        this.cellules = new ArrayList<Cellule>(); 
    } 

    // methods 
    public int getSize(){ 
        return this.cellules.size(); 
    } 

    public int addElement(Cellule e){ 
        if(e.getOwner() != this)  
            e.setOwner(this); 
        this.cellules.add(e); 
        return this.cellules.indexOf(e); 
    } 

    public Cellule getElementAtIndex(int index){ 
        return this.cellules.get(index); 
    } 
}
```

And the JavaScript (ES6) code for doing the same :

```
class Cellule {  
    constructor(name){  
        // properties 
        this.name = name; 
        this.owner = null; 
    }  
} 

class Owner{ 
    constructor(){  
        // properties 
        this.cellules = []; 
    } 

    // methods 
    getSize(){ 
       return this.cellules.length; 
    } 

    addElement(cellule){ 
        if(cellule.owner != this)  
            cellule.owner = this; 
        return this.cellules.push(cellule); 
    } 

    getElementAtIndex(index){ 
        return this.cellules[index]; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you can't make private members (properties or methods) in ES6 syntax, but you can in ES5 syntax, like this :

```
var MyClass = function() {
    var _name = "John"; // private property

    this.getName = function() { // public method
        return _name; // which returns the private property
    }
};
```